# What's a good mobile navigation strategy for hierarchies with few children?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, navigation

Say your IA hierarchy is like this:

- Main section A

  - Feature 1
  - Feature 2
  - Feature 3
- Main Section B (List/tableview)

  - Item

    - Detail 1
    - Detail 2
    - Detail 3
- Main Section C

The traditional iOS-style approach would be to use a Tab Bar at the bottom for the Main Sections.  So far, so good.  My question is, where does the sub-navigation for the Detail views of the Section B items go?  Are there any canonical examples of this?  One approach would be just very short lists in a table view, but that seems so lame and outdated.

This would also apply to the Features of Main Section A.  Perhaps a subnav Tab Bar but above the content, below a top header?

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE. I'd suggest adding a wireframe to help the community understand your layout as some of the terms Tab Bar, Main Section, etc are more ambiguous that you might think

Comment: It's pretty late but...you have a good example of this on UX site itself. Take a look top bar with "Questions Tags Users..." and how its content/siblings change.

Comment: @adriano, The mobile UX is really nice, but it doesn't have the problem I'm having—subsections underneath the main sections (i.e. Questions, Tags, Users...)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to philip's answer, there is also an other implementation. I really like the the 'pushover'-style. You can find [a demo and tutorial here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/). The tutorial isn't for a mobile menu but the idea remains the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most common example of handling navigating to children on mobile would be the traditional hamburger menu. You can continue expanding as much as required. Note the "+" next to "Image Gallery" which will expand another list of children.

[image]